# Linq Group By on Sets

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

While working with `Linq` on Grouping sets, I found a problem while the query is returning the list.

My Code is written in `LinqPad`

```
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<RequestEntry> RequestEntries = new List<RequestEntry>(){   
            new RequestEntry{
                RequestId = 1, 
                RequestedDate = new DateTime(2018, 06, 01), 
                ApproverUserId = "STEVES", 
                ApproverUserName = "Steve Smith",
                AuthorizerUserId = "JAMESS",
                AuthorizerUserName = "James Sutherland"
            }, 
            new RequestEntry{
                RequestId = 1, 
                RequestedDate = new DateTime(2018, 06, 01), 
                ApproverUserId = "GRAHAMS", 
                ApproverUserName = "Graham Smith",
                AuthorizerUserId = "THABANGM",
                AuthorizerUserName = "Thabang Moroe"
            }, 
            new RequestEntry{
                RequestId = 2, 
                RequestedDate = new DateTime(2018, 06, 02), 
                ApproverUserId = "STEVES", 
                ApproverUserName = "Steve Smith",
                AuthorizerUserId = "JAMESS",
                AuthorizerUserName = "James Sutherland"
            }, 
            new RequestEntry{
                RequestId = 3, 
                RequestedDate = new DateTime(2018, 06, 03), 
                ApproverUserId = "ROBINS", 
                ApproverUserName = "Robin Smith",
                AuthorizerUserId = "TOMH",
                AuthorizerUserName = "Tom Harrision"
            }, 
            new RequestEntry{
                RequestId = 3, 
                RequestedDate = new DateTime(2018, 06, 03), 
                ApproverUserId = "CHRISS", 
                ApproverUserName = "Chris Smith",
                AuthorizerUserId = "TOMH",
                AuthorizerUserName = "Tom Harrision"
            }, 
            new RequestEntry{
                RequestId = 3, 
                RequestedDate = new DateTime(2018, 06, 03), 
                ApproverUserId = "LIAMS", 
                ApproverUserName = "Liam Smith",
                AuthorizerUserId = "TOMH",
                AuthorizerUserName = "Tom Harrision"
            }
        };

        var results = (
            from r in RequestEntries
            group r by new
            {
                r.RequestId, r.RequestedDate
            } into g
            select new RequestWithApprover(){
                RequestId = g.Key.RequestId, 
                RequestedDate = g.Key.RequestedDate, 
                ApproverUserIds = g.Select(c => c.ApproverUserId).ToList(), 
                RequestApprovers = g.Select(c => new RequestApprover(){
                    ApproverUserName = c.ApproverUserName, 
                    ApproverUserId = c.ApproverUserId
                    }).ToList(), 
                RequestAuthorizers = g.Select(c => new RequestAuthorizer(){
                    AuthorizerUserName = c.AuthorizerUserName, 
                    AuthorizerUserId = c.AuthorizerUserId
                    }).ToList()
                }).ToList();

        results.Dump();
    }


public class RequestEntry
{
    public int RequestId
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string ApproverUserId
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string ApproverUserName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string AuthorizerUserId
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string AuthorizerUserName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public DateTime RequestedDate
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public class RequestApprover
{
    public string ApproverUserId
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string ApproverUserName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public class RequestAuthorizer
{
    public string AuthorizerUserId
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string AuthorizerUserName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public class RequestWithApprover
{
    public int RequestId
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public DateTime RequestedDate
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public List<string> ApproverUserIds
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public List<RequestApprover> RequestApprovers
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public List<RequestAuthorizer> RequestAuthorizers
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

What I found is, For `RequestID` =3, the Number of `RequestAuthorizer` items should be 1, but it had multiplied. I found that in `RequestID` =3 the Maximum items in any list is 3, the `RequestAuthorizer` to multiplies to that Number. Refer below snapshot highlighted of the result:

[image]

Technically, In `RequestId`=3 the `List<RequestAuthorizer>` should only contain the Item of Tom Harrision and the count should be one.

How could I correct it?

Comment: I think this code just works according to this data since you have 3 `RequestEntry` belongs to  `DateTime(2018, 06, 03)` which AuthorizerUserId equals TOMH. Why do you expect return just one item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about grouping the RequestAuthorizer?

```
var results = (
        from r in RequestEntries
        group r by new
        {
            r.RequestId, r.RequestedDate
        } into g
        select new RequestWithApprover(){
            RequestId = g.Key.RequestId, 
            RequestedDate = g.Key.RequestedDate, 
            ApproverUserIds = g.Select(c => c.ApproverUserId).ToList(), 
            RequestApprovers = g.Select(c => new RequestApprover(){
                ApproverUserName = c.ApproverUserName, 
                ApproverUserId = c.ApproverUserId
                }).ToList(), 
            RequestAuthorizers = g.
                GroupBy(g1 => new {
                    g1.AuthorizerUserName, 
                    g1.AuthorizerUserId }).
                Select(c => new RequestAuthorizer(){
                AuthorizerUserName = c.Key.AuthorizerUserName, 
                AuthorizerUserId = c.Key.AuthorizerUserId
                }).ToList()
            }).ToList();
```

Comment: Since you are grouping them, `c` will be an `IGrouping<anonymous,RequestEntry>`, and therefore your code won't compile unless you replace `c.AuthorizerUserName` with `c.Key.AuthorizerUserName`. Same for the Id.

Comment: correct, this answer was just from the top of my head, suggesting to group on the grouping, edited the answer anyway

Comment: you actually modified the wrong one, `g => new {
                    g.AuthorizerUserName, 
                    g.AuthorizerUserId }` is fine, it's `new RequestAuthorizer(){
                AuthorizerUserName = c.Key.AuthorizerUserName, 
                AuthorizerUserId = c.Key.AuthorizerUserId
                }` that had to be edited

Comment: Hi, @JochemVanHespen Thank you very much for your input and it resolved my issue. Actually, there is a small correction to be made, where `g` can not be used again hence I had to amend it as `RequestAuthorizers = g.GroupBy(g1 => new { g1.AuthorizerUserName,  g1.AuthorizerUserId })`

Comment: great I'll edit the post! as I said the answer was more suggesting to group on the grouping :D thnx for accepting my answer!